# Why is there an extra bronze badge in opposite SE accounts?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have 5 silvers and 19 bronzes in Stack Overflow. I have 13 bronzes on DBA. I've synchronized my SE accounts between all sites I am a member of. However when I visit SO, it says I have 14 bronzes in DBA. When I visit DBA, it says I have 20 bronzes in SO.

Is there a bug with how the synchronization works? Or is there a "hidden" badge I've earned on both sites that I just don't see when I visit either site?

Only reason I bring it up is in case there is a bug.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're looking at your network accounts on a site, e.g. SO from DBA, this is pulling from a network-level cache that can sometimes get out-of-sync.

We periodically fix this cache for all users (which is very expensive), but this is usually not needed.  The implementation is such that upon getting another badge or more reputation, the network cache will be fixed to the latest value.

We're running one of these global fixes this weekend - if you're still seeing this after then, let us know.

Comment: Fixed the issue.

Comment: we can probably tag this discussion "status-completed"